# Angular - Check if queryParams are existing or not on the root path (/)

Tags: angular, routes, url-parameters

I have a legacy application written in Vaadin which needs to be ported to Angular 15, notably using the same URL structure. I'm almost done with it. The one thing missing is that I need to check if **no** URL query param exists on the root path. In this case, I need to display a popup.

Short:

- http://xxx/?a=1234 <-- this is what the customer will get from the sales person
- http://xxx/ <-- this should show a popup, like "wrong URL, contact sales"

I am subscribing to the route queryParams in `onInit`. My first attempt was to simply check for the param's existence within the `subscribe` block and trigger the action that way. This worked for URLs with no queryParams, but also got triggered if params were existing. I boiled it down, introduced a counter and figured that there were actually two iterations within the subscribe block with params, the first returning an empty object.

Here is the running app:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xenodochial-rosalind-3mtpr5

The subscribe part looks like this. Same thing if it's in the `constructor()`:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('onInit start');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((p) => {
      console.log('count:' + this.count + ' => ' + JSON.stringify(p));
      this.params = p;
      this.count++;
    });
    console.log('onInit end');
  }
```

I would expect something like this if there are query parameters:

```
onInit start
count:1 => { "a":"1234" }
onInit end
```

Instead, I get

```
onInit start
count:1 => {}
onInit end
count:2 => {"a":"1234"}
```

I tried several things, nothing worked:

- moved the block to `constructor()`
- used `snapshot`
- checked if `AfterViewInit()` would have the final result
- tried to find a way to wait for the `subscribe()` to finish
- duckduckgo'ed a lot
- ...

Any idea/hint highly appreciated.

Edit: *I actually need a way to know when the whole parameter loading process is done, to trigger the popup or continue.*

Edit: `app.module.ts`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot([])],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your inputs. I found the easiest way to do it (maybe not the smartest):

In `app.components.ts`, I implement `OnInit`. In there, I do it the java script way:

```
if (!window.location.href.includes ...) {
```

Works and doesn't interfere with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Router `Observable` are ([BehaviorSubjects](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_state.ts#L65-L70)) different to RxJS `Subject` observables.
This kind of observables gives you an initial value (what is null, or empty object) first.

The easiest way is to skip the first value.

```
 this.route.queryParams.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((p) => {
      console.log('counter:' + this.count + ' => ' + JSON.stringify(p));
      this.params = p;
      this.count++;
    });
```

For the first params, if you reload the page (not change the url, reload or at first load) you can use the **snapshot**

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const params: any = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
    console.log("Params", params);
  }
```

#### Important, too: provide Router:

In a standalone component you need to use the new `provideRouter`function!

```
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

......

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter([])],
});
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than counting, but in the end, it doesn't solve the issue. When I skip the first value, it won't even jump in there with no parameters. Which means, I still don't have a good spot to trigger the popup.

Comment: You need to combine it with the snapshot. Thats the way to go. Snapshot at beginning. And subscribe fires if you change only the params.

Comment: Where would I take the snapshot?

Comment: In the `ngOnInit` part.

Comment: Would you mind updating your code snippet above? This sounds like a good plan, but I don't really see how to achieve it. Monitor `this.params` using `OnChanges`?
Whenever I take a snapshot, it's empty.

Comment: Thanks for the update - the snapshot is always `{}`. Literally always. I could also say `const params = {}`. I would still need to know when the `subscribe()` ends.

Comment: Did you use `RouterModule` You need to use it. Without it the snapshot is empty.

Comment: Yep, will copy the code snippet into the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Look to the `provideRouter`part.

Comment: Thanks @flo, I won't be able to test this within the next few weeks. I'll fwd it to my teammates to check.